# Google Vision in a Vue.js/ Django REST appliaction

Tags: vue.js, google-vision

I would like to implement google Vision API in my  Vue.js/ Django REST application. I have browsed through the oficial documentation but I still don't understand how to do it.
It seems that the API is only available server side (C#, Go, Java, Node...) but I would like to use client side in Vue.js.

It also seems that we can also access the API through this endpoint: `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_API_KEY,`
Is it possible to send my picture using `axios` to this endpoint and get results back? How should I format my request?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to implement Google Vision Api in a Vue.js/ Django app, this is how I resolved it:

```
checkImageLabels: function() {
      this.picToCheck = this.image.dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
      const data = {
        "requests" : [{
          "features": [{
            "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
          }],
          "image": {
            "content": this.picToCheck
          }
        }]
      }
      axios.post(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${this.apiKey}`, data)  
    }
```

You have to have "axios" imported into your project and a valid Google Cloud APIKey. As for the input format, I use base64 pictures and I clear the header with a regular expression.